# how to suppress error 1606- could not access network location in wix

Tags: c#, wix

I am installing some component in network location.
 At the time of uninstall, if network location is unavailable because remote machine is not on. setup is giving following error
`Error 1606 could not access network location`

Is there any way to suppress this error and continue the uninstallation process? 
If the files on Network location(that is unavailable at the time) are not deleted then its ok for me.

Answer (score -1):

To fix your issue you could try and set the component to `Permanent ="yes"` which will not un-install that component and in theory you should not get that error.

However personally I would re-think the implementation to get around adding files to the network location (maybe add the network files on first run of your application?).

Comment: OK thanks for the response, obviously someone dislikes me! :)

Comment: Dont loose ur heart ;-) :-) :-)